# How read single page from doc file

Tags: php

I have a doc file that contains multiple pages and I want to read single page at a time. Any idea how to read single page ??

Comment: What version of Word are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

For Word 2007 you are looking at the Open XML File format, which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx).